Lucas 1972 Neutrality of Money Proof of derivation
Lucas (1972) Neutrality of Money section 3 has following set up.
$U(c,n)$ is Utility function of consumption and labor (or producing labor output). $U_c (c,n) >0$ and $U_n (c,n)<0$. Further, the noninferiority conditions hold for leisure, $U_{cc} +U_{cn}<0$ and $U_{nn} +U_{nc}<0$ . We have following Kuhn-Tucker conditions for the objective function.

$U_c(c,n)-p\mu<= 0$, with equality if $c$>0,
$U_n(c,n)+p\mu<= 0$, with equality if $n$>0, and
$p(n-c)-\lambda >=0$, with equality if $n$>0

These three conditions can solve for $c,n,$ and $p\mu$ as a function of $\lambda/p.$ The function $h(\lambda/p)$ is the solution for $p\mu$, which is positive, increasing, and continuously differentiable.
I have  trouble understating that $h(\lambda/p)$ can be an increasing function. We can infer from conditions 1 and 2 that the function is positive, and continuous. However, since marginal utility function is a decreasing function, I can not put my head around the idea why $h(\lambda/p)$ be an increasing function. Moreover, I tried substituting Cob-Douglas utility function $U(c,n) = c^\alpha n^{\alpha -1}$, where $\alpha\in(0,1)$, which will satisfy concavity, continuity, and noninferiority conditions. By substituring the Cob-Douglas type utility function, the derived $h(\lambda/p)$ is positive, decreasing, and continuous function.

Are you sure you substituted the correct Cobb-Douglas? It can be a typo, but in your Cobb Douglas the exponent of $n$ should be $1-\alpha$, not $\alpha-1$

I agree that usual Cobb-Douglas function is of the form $\alpha, 1-\alpha$. However, I wanted to set up the $U_n(C,n)<0$, and $U_C(C,n) >0$. For that reason, I set up the function $U(C,n) = C^{\alpha} n^{\alpha-1}$.
